# nginx errors with very large headers

Tags: http, nginx, grafana, influxdb

When the user selects the ‘All’ filter on our dashboards, most queries fail and we get this error: 502 - Bad Gateway in Grafana. If it refreshes the page, the errors disappear and the dashboards work. We use an nginx as a reverse proxy and imagine that the problem is linked to URI size or headers. We made an attempt to increase the buffers: large_client_header_buffers 32 1024k. A second attempt was to change the InfluxDB method from GET to POST. Errors have diminished, but they still happen constantly. Our configuration uses nginx + Grafana + InfluxDB.

When using All nodes as filter on our dashboards ( the maximum of possible information), most of the queries return an failure (502 - Bad Gateway) on grafana. We have Keycloak for authetication and an nginx, working as an reverse proxy in front of our grafana server and somehow the problem is linked to it, when acessing the grafana server directly, trhough an ssh-tunnel for example, we do not experience the failure.

nginx log error example:

<*my_ip*> - - [22/Dec/2021:14:35:27 -0300] "POST /grafana/api/datasources/proxy/1/query?db=telegraf&epoch=ms HTTP/1.1" 502 3701 "https://<*my_domain*>/grafana/d/gQzec6oZk/compute-nodes-administrative-dashboard?orgId=1&refresh=1m" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36" "-"

below prints of the error in grafana and the configuration variables

[variables we use in them as a whole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEpp0.png)

[error in grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAmtP.png)

Comment: try  add client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 4k;

Comment: we already did it before, and it did not solve the problem

Comment: https://community.grafana.com/t/431-request-header-fields-too-large/55322

Comment: our problem is different Jan, when I use grafana bypassing mfa/nginx I can use dashboards normally